# error: '.class' expected amongst 7 other errors

Tags: java

Sorry im a beginner with java programming. Can someone see why my program is giving me these error messages?

Error message reads:

```
MonthlyPhoneCostVer2.java:13: error: '.class' expected
double res = isCost(double a, double b, double c, double d, double x, double y, double z);
                           ^
MonthlyPhoneCostVer2.java:13: error: ';' expected
double res = isCost(double a, double b, double c, double d, double x, double y, double z);
                            ^
MonthlyPhoneCostVer2.java:13: error: <identifier> expected
double res = isCost(double a, double b, double c, double d, double x, double y, double z);
                                       ^
MonthlyPhoneCostVer2.java:13: error: <identifier> expected
double res = isCost(double a, double b, double c, double d, double x, double y, double z);
                                                 ^
MonthlyPhoneCostVer2.java:13: error: <identifier> expected
double res = isCost(double a, double b, double c, double d, double x, double y, double z);
                                                           ^
MonthlyPhoneCostVer2.java:13: error: <identifier> expected
double res = isCost(double a, double b, double c, double d, double x, double y, double z);
                                                                     ^
MonthlyPhoneCostVer2.java:13: error: <identifier> expected
double res = isCost(double a, double b, double c, double d, double x, double y, double z);
                                                                               ^
MonthlyPhoneCostVer2.java:13: error: ';' expected
double res = isCost(double a, double b, double c, double d, double x, double y, double z);
                                                                                        ^
8 errors
```

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class MonthlyPhoneCostVer2{
public static void main (String [] args){
double a = 2.50; // cost/min for day call
double b = 0.55; // cost/min for evening and weekend calls
double c = 50; // static monthly subscription cost
double d = 0.60; // cost for opening a phone call . cant have ',' in value
double x = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Number of Phone Calls?"));
double y = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Minutes of day calls"));
double z = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Minutes of evening weekend calls"));
double res = isCost(double a, double b, double c, double d, double x, double y, double z);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Total Cost of Phone Fees is: " + res);
}
public static double isCost(double a, double b, double c, double d, double x, double y, double z){
return ((x*d) + (y*a) + (z*b) + c);
}
}
```

Comment: [tag:javascript] tag removed. This question has *nothing* to do with javaScript.

Comment: oh yikes, sorry, im a newbie, thought the code is a script from java idk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method call to `isCost` has ***incorrect*** syntax. This

```
double res = isCost(double a, double b, double c, double d, double x, double y, double z);
```

should be

```
double res = isCost(a, b, c, d, x, y, z);
```

I'm not clear why you felt the need to add the type information (again) from the caller, but that is simply not correct.

Comment: Ahhhh, I see. I don't why I did what I did. Issue solved. But may I ask another thing if thats okay. What do you think about the structure of my code, language, newlines, semi braces locations etc. is it a program that is easy to follow or is it overcomplicated, messy, non-chronological? Sorry, just would like some feedback :)

Comment: And Id also know why I see many codes, where within the parameters within a non-main method, they add arbitrary variable declerations that dont corelate with any other variables in the program? Is it not just easier to set the parameters with variables with declared values?

Comment: Your code badly needs indentation. Your variable names are **not** meaningful. And your method name `isCost` performs a calculation (and does not return a boolean). Your code could use refactoring to address those issues. As for your follow on to that, I cannot say without seeing said method(s). Many methods use local variables. What are you asking there?

Comment: Right! Intendation, like instead of int a I could have int dayCost, int b could be int eveWeekendCost etc right. And yeah regarding the boolean thing, I was going to ask another question if I really need to have a seperate method to perform the caluclation, because I have another version where I just perform the calulcation within the JOptionPane class. It looked like this: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Total Cost of Phone Fees is: " + ((x*d) + (y*a) + (z*b) + c));. Im still in the process of figuring out when do i really need a seperate methods, perhaps for booleans then?

Comment: And what I mean with the parameter thingy is that, like in this example:             public class SquareMain {
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result, n;
        
        n = 3
        result = square(n);
        System.out.println("Square of 3 is: " + result);
        
        n = 4
        result = square(n); 
        System.out.println("Square of 4 is: " + result);
    }

 static int square(int i) {
        return i * i;
    }
}   He uses i instead of n, so im wondering, doesnt the method want to fetch the value of n? why i?

Comment: You never "need" separate methods, but they can make your code easier to read and reason about; and should be used for that reason. As for my comment about `boolean`, the method name should at least ***hint*** at what it does. `isCost` implies that it's a method that *tests* whether something is a cost. `calculateCost` would be a better name then (for what you have here). Note it is the ***names*** that I think need improving (and as I mentioned, your code is not indented at all).

Comment: Because the local name of the parameter is completely unrelated to the name from the caller. Java is **always** pass-by-value. So the thing that is passed is the value of the `int` (not the name). And in languages that are pass-by-reference, it's still just a local label for the reference.

Comment: Right but I still think its a little bit confusing, because if I replace the i with n in the provided example, the code would still run as usual. so why have i instead of n I dont get it

Comment: Because you could call it from any method with any name; if you limited it to `n` then `n` would be taken forevermore in your program (which is known as a "global"). You don't need to provide `i` or `n`, you could call `square(3)` just as easily; does that make sense now?

Comment: hmm i dony know im not too familar with the concept of global etc, i just think it makes sense to call it int n instead of int i because we are taking the value of n into that method.......

Comment: And assigning that value to a parameter named ***anything*** at all where the parameter matches. Simple as that. Again, what if your method used meaningful variable names: `static int square(int numberToSquare) { return numberToSquare * numberToSquare; }` - now it's clear that `square` is going to use `numberToSquare` to do something, and that the caller might have more than one thing to square (and that thing might, or might not, be called `numberToSquare` because the caller might have `hypotenuse` which needs squaring)... just as an example.

Comment: ah i get it now, im thinking of parameters in a wrong sense, I can call it whatever as long as it matches ... (the parameters??)

Comment: Technically, as long as the ["method signature"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) matches - but yes. Pay particular attention to that link and the **note** *Definition: Two of the components of a method declaration comprise the method signature—the method's name and the parameter types.* Parameter names are not included in that definition, but parameter types are **very** relevant.

Comment: Got it, amazing! Thank you, I enjoyed our conversation. Enjoy your day.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
double res = isCost(a, b,  c, d, x, y, z);
```

Comment: Yep thank you, issue solved! May I also ask, what do you think about the general layout of my code, is it well structured? Efficent? Overcomplicated? Messy? Any steps that are not necessary? Can I disregard some steps? Make the code shorter? Id be grateful to recieve some feedback!

Comment: @Zerenity, use your variable name more constructively, something that actually matches the logic, also if your datatype is the same, try to use it once to reduce redundancy.

Comment: Ahhh redundency was the word I was looking for. Right. so instead of double a = ...;, double b =...;, double c=...;,  have double a, b, c; ... a = ..., b = ... c = ... right. and okay, so instead of thinking like mathematical variables, think indendation variables based on natural language right

Comment: @Zerenity, yes, you can google and find a lot of good programming practises

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MonthlyPhoneCostVer2 
{
    public static void main (String [] args) 
    {
        double a = 2.50; // cost/min for day call
        double b = 0.55; // cost/min for evening and weekend calls
        double c = 50; // static monthly subscription cost
        double d = 0.60; // cost for opening a phone call . cant have ',' in value
        double x = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Number of Phone Calls?"));
        double y = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Minutes of day calls"));
        double z = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Minutes of evening weekend calls"));
        double res = isCost(a,b,c,d,x,y,z);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Total Cost of Phone Fees is: " + res);
    }

    public static double isCost(double a, double b, double c, double d, double x, double y, double z) 
    {
        return ((x*d) + (y*a) + (z*b) + c);
    }
}
```

The double variables were already defined. So no need to define the variables inside the function.